# Why is 30 not printed in the console. Can any one give me a step by step execution of the code. Thanks

Tags: java

```
public class ContinueExample {
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        int[] numbers = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };

        for (int x : numbers) { 
            if (x == 30) { 
                continue; 
            }

            System.out.print(x);
            System.out.print("\n"); 
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

10
20
40
50

Comment: Your debugger can do that easily.  Why are you asking us to do it?

Comment: Because the continue oversteps the code what is after it.

Comment: Step 1: that is not Vb.NET code.  Dont pick random tags

Answer (score 1):

```
  if (x == 30) {
 continue;
```

means if x is 30, it will jump to start of the next loop.